# How to get more than 10 documents from solr

Tags: angularjs, solr

I am new to solr i have a solr application running and started querying it from the angular application i was able get the results from the solr but i am getting only the first 10 documents but there are more no of documents indexed 
my code is :

```
angular.element.ajax({
               url: "http://localhost:8983/solr/food/select",
               data: {
                   "q": $scope.searchString,
                   "wt": "json"

               },
               traditional: true,
               cache: true,
               async: true,
               dataType: 'jsonp',
               success: function (data) {
                   //and when we get the query back we
                   //stick the results in the scope
                   $scope.$apply(function () {
                       $scope.results = data.response.docs;
                       console.log("result from solr is  ",$scope.results)

                   });
               }                        });
               },
               jsonp: 'json.wrf'
           });
```

How to get all the docs indexed from the solr??
help me please

Comment: or does not needed `},jsonp: 'json.wrf'});`, or needed more code;

Comment: can u elaborate please??

Comment: It seems to me, copy\paste error there; Probably do not need 4 bottom line (`}  });`).

Comment: If you are always looking for more than 10 rows, then change the defaults for select handler in solrconfig.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add following params(**start** and **rows**):

```
 angular.element.ajax({
                   url: "http://localhost:8983/solr/food/select",
                   data: {
                       "q": $scope.searchString, 
                       "start":10,//starting from this index
                        "rows":20,//count of results 
                       "wt": "json"

                   },
                   traditional: true,
                   cache: true,
                   async: true,
                   dataType: 'jsonp',
                   success: function (data) {
                       //and when we get the query back we
                       //stick the results in the scope
                       $scope.$apply(function () {
                           $scope.results = data.response.docs;
                           console.log("result from solr is  ",$scope.results)

                       });
                   }                        });
                   },
                   jsonp: 'json.wrf'
               });
```

Then it will work